# Axios can't submit Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, axios

From this request:

```
localhost/goods?ids[]=1&ids[]=2
```

My Vue file:

```
var array = [1, 2];
let json = JSON.stringify(array);
console.log(json);
axios.get('http://localhost/goods', json).then(function(res) {
            if (res.code == 200) {
                console.log("ok");
            }
        }
```

**Note that using axios follow the request url `localhost/goods?ids[]=1&ids[]=2`. How to implement this URL request method?**

Comment: Define what do you mean seems to be wrong?

Comment: @Zamrony P. Juhara I hope to use to axios follow this request `localhost/goods?ids[]=1&ids[]=2 `

Answer (score 0):

You're using it wrong.

The second parameter to get should be JS object having `params` property.

From the documentation-

```
axios.get('/user', {
  params: {
    ID: 12345
  }
 }).then(function (response) {
   console.log(response);})
```